# CSS3 :nth-child(odd) /even isn't consistent

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got a list with hidden and visible items. 
The visible items have got a class called active. I am trying to apply `:nth-child(odd)` or -`:nth-of-type(even)` only to these specific visible items, but the result is totally random.

I expect: yellow, green, yellow, green, yellow.

Result:  yellow, yellow, green, yellow, green, green.

I thought I would be able to filter on classname as well as node. But obviously that isn't the case.

```
    <ul>
      <li>hide</li>
      <li class="active">visible</li>
      <li>hide</li>
      <li class="active">visible</li>
      <li class="active">visible</li>
      <li>hide</li>
      <li class="active">visible</li>
      <li class="active">visible</li>
      <li>hide</li>
      <li class="active">visible</li>
    </ul>
```

Style:

```
li {
   background-color:red;
   display:none;
}

li.active {
  display:block;
}

li.active:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:yellow;
}

li.active:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:green;
}
```

Is there a way around this?

EDIT:
I cannot use jQuery or any other library, only native js. 
In real life I have 50+ list items filled with images and text, therefore removing the invisible ones form the DOM and putting back is probably not a good idea.

Comment: This is because having or not having the `.active` class, or being visible/hidden, doesn't change whether an element is an oddly- or evenly-occurring child. In other words, your class and pseudo-class selectors don't filter down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <li></li>                // odd , display none   
  <li class="active"></li> // even                 green
  <li></li>                // odd , display none
  <li class="active"></li> // even                 green
  <li class="active"></li> // odd                  yellow
  <li></li>                // even, display none
  <li class="active"></li> // odd                  yellow
  <li class="active"></li> // even                 green
  <li></li>                // odd , display none
  <li class="active"></li> // even                 green
```

what doesn't make sense?  What're your empty `<li>`s for?  Considering doing something different there... if they're for spacing, add a "spacer" class to some LIs and put margin/padding on it.

---

Assuming you want the row-colors to change dynamically depending on what's visible, you can't do this with pure CSS. It's simple using jQuery though, something like:

```
$( '#ul li:visible' ).each( function( i ){
    $( this )[ (1&i) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'active' );
} )
```

Comment: Well looking at the style li.active:nth-child(odd) one would assume that you could get odd/even from a certain class type

Comment: `nth-child` applies to nodes, that's it.  It doesn't filter based on class or anything else.  If you threw some `<div>`'s in there, it'd count them too.

Comment: They are not really empty, they contain the same stuff as the others but need to be hidden depending on how you toggle them via a navigation. I just made them empty here to clarify things

Comment: Assuming you want the row-colors to change dynamically depending on what's visible, you can't do this with pure CSS.  It's simple using jQuery though, something like: `$( '#ul li:visible' ).each( function( i ){ $( this )[ (1&i) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'active' ); } )`

Comment: I ended up adding odd/even classes with a JS loop and if (i % 2 === 0). Thanks for the tips

Comment: `(i % 2 === 0)` is the same thing as `1&i` (well it's reversed)

Answer (score 2):

It makes perfect sense because the empty list items are colored as well.

Most elegant solution: Remove the rendering of empty list elements.

Another possibility would be to use jQuery in order to remove the empty list elements after the document has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in Firefox.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LI.css" />
Test
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li class="active">2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li class="active">4</li>
<li class="active">5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li class="active">7</li>
<li class="active">8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li class="active">A</li>
</ul>
```

2, 4, 8 & A get green backgrounds, but 1, 3, & 9 don't show up (display: none)

Comment: Sorry, Pata, I misunderstood what you wanted. As noted above, it displays odd or even based on which child it is, not which displayed child it is.

Comment: I'm curious how you feel comfortable changing the class to "active" or not, but don't feel comfortable removing the lines that are not displayed in the same manner.